# Parse RTF file using Tika won't parse ordered lists

Tags: java, rtf, apache-tika

I'm trying to parse RTF file to plain text using Tika.

When I'm trying to parse .rtf file with ordered list items, the parser replaces numbers of list items with whitespace.

Do you have any tips I could use?

Original text:

[image: Original text]

Actual output:

[image: Actual output]

I'm using code below.

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream("files/rtf_auto.rtf");
AutoDetectParser autoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser();

BodyContentHandler contentHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
autoDetectParser.parse(is, contentHandler, metadata, new ParseContext());

System.out.println(contentHandler);
```

Comment: Try asking Apache Tika for the XHTML version of the file, instead of the Plain Text version you're doing now?

Comment: When I create XHTML from RTF, the list is still defined as an unordered list instead of an ordered one.

Comment: Sounds like a bug - https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/TIKA/summary is the place to report them